# URL Encode showing as 404 pagees

Tags: url, urlencode

New here.  I manage several Wordpress sites, but Screaming Frog SEO Spider is showing UTF-8 encoded URLs giving 404 errors for only this site.  The site itself is working as intended, with URLs in the browser working correctly, yet pretty much every link on the site is "doubled" in the crawler, with the correct link showing 200 status, and then a duplicate 404 with:

Address:
`https://xxxxx.com/locations/<%=%20_.escape(url)%20%>`

URL Encoded Address:
`https://xxxxx.com/locations/%3C%25=%20_.escape(url)%20%25%3E`

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCMpI.jpg

The site was running PHP 5.6, so I figured it could have been an out of date PHP issue, so we upgraded to PHP 7.3, but the issue remains.

Error logs from FTP/File Manager aren't showing any issues that I can see.  Using Custom Structure permalink in WordPress 5.2.2, mysqli  5.7.26/mysqlnd 5.0.12.

.htaceess: (hidden domain/admin info)

```
text/x-generic .htaccess ( UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines )
# BEGIN WpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxxxxxx.com
# Start WPFC Exclude
# End WPFC Exclude
# Start_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=admin|xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
# End_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxxxxxxxxxxx.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit|Twitterbot|LinkedInBot|WhatsApp|Mediatoolkitbot)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(WP\sFastest\sCache\sPreload(\siPhone\sMobile)?\s*Bot)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/){2}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !comment_author_
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !safirmobilswitcher=mobil
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(\bCrMo\b|CriOS|Android.*Chrome\/[.0-9]*\s(Mobile)?|\bDolfin\b|Opera.*Mini|Opera.*Mobi|Android.*Opera|Mobile.*OPR\/[0-9.]+|Coast\/[0-9.]+|Skyfire|Mobile\sSafari\/[.0-9]*\sEdge|IEMobile|MSIEMobile|fennec|firefox.*maemo|(Mobile|Tablet).*Firefox|Firefox.*Mobile|FxiOS|bolt|teashark|Blazer|Version.*Mobile.*Safari|Safari.*Mobile|MobileSafari|Tizen|UC.*Browser|UCWEB|baiduboxapp|baidubrowser|DiigoBrowser|Puffin|\bMercury\b|Obigo|NF-Browser|NokiaBrowser|OviBrowser|OneBrowser|TwonkyBeamBrowser|SEMC.*Browser|FlyFlow|Minimo|NetFront|Novarra-Vision|MQQBrowser|MicroMessenger|Android.*PaleMoon|Mobile.*PaleMoon|Android|blackberry|\bBB10\b|rim\stablet\sos|PalmOS|avantgo|blazer|elaine|hiptop|palm|plucker|xiino|Symbian|SymbOS|Series60|Series40|SYB-[0-9]+|\bS60\b|Windows\sCE.*(PPC|Smartphone|Mobile|[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{3})|Window\sMobile|Windows\sPhone\s[0-9.]+|WCE;|Windows\sPhone\s10.0|Windows\sPhone\s8.1|Windows\sPhone\s8.0|Windows\sPhone\sOS|XBLWP7|ZuneWP7|Windows\sNT\s6\.[23]\;\sARM\;|\biPhone.*Mobile|\biPod|\biPad|Apple-iPhone7C2|MeeGo|Maemo|J2ME\/|\bMIDP\b|\bCLDC\b|webOS|hpwOS|\bBada\b|BREW).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f [or]
RewriteCond /home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "index\.(html|htm)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Mon, 29 Oct 1923 20:30:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END WpFastestCache
# BEGIN GzipWpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddType x-font/woff .woff
AddType x-font/ttf .ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE x-font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype font/ttf font/eot font/otf
</IfModule>
# END GzipWpFastestCache
# BEGIN LBCWpFastestCache
<FilesMatch "\.(webm|ogg|mp4|ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|js|css|swf|x-html|css|xml|js|woff|woff2|otf|ttf|svg|eot)(\.gz)?$">
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
AddType application/font-woff2 .woff2
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType video/webm A10368000
ExpiresByType video/ogg A10368000
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A10368000
ExpiresByType image/webp A10368000
ExpiresByType image/gif A10368000
ExpiresByType image/png A10368000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A10368000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A10368000
ExpiresByType image/ico A10368000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A10368000
ExpiresByType text/css A10368000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A10368000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A10368000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A10368000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A10368000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype A10368000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-truetype A10368000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Expires "max-age=A10368000, public"
Header unset ETag
Header set Connection keep-alive
FileETag None
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END LBCWpFastestCache

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php70” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 300
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1500
   php_value memory_limit 512M
   php_value post_max_size 32M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
   php_flag log_errors On
   php_value error_log "/home/xxxxxxxxx/public_html/phpupgradelog.log"
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 300
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1500
   php_value memory_limit 512M
   php_value post_max_size 32M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
   php_flag log_errors On
   php_value error_log "/home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/phpupgradelog.log"
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
```

Expected output: Keeping the Status 200 links that are showing in Screaming Frog SEO, and removing the 404 URL encoding links that are showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue with the crawler tool blindly pulling in a href script tag, and counting as a URL.  They are fixing the issue on their end.

Solved!

```
<script id='wpvpm-menu-item' type='text/html'><li>
    <% if(children.length > 0) { %>
        <a href="#" class="has-children <%= _.escape(classes.join(' ')) %>" title="<%= _.escape(attr_title) %>"><%= title %></a>
        <div class="mp-level">
            <div class="mp-level-header">
                <h2><%= title %></h2>
                <a class="mp-back" href="#"><%= WpvPushMenu.back %></a>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <% if(! (/^\s*$/.test(url)) ) { %>
                    <li><a href="<%= _.escape(url) %>" class="<%= _.escape(classes.join(' ')) %>" title="<%= _.escape(attr_title) %>"><%= title %></a></li>
                <% } %>
                <%= content %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% } else { %>
        <a href="<%= _.escape(url) %>" class="<%= _.escape(classes.join(' ')) %>" title="<%= _.escape(attr_title) %>"><%= title %></a>
    <% } %>
</li></script>
```